# Mechanics behind Pringle Ring

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, statics, stability

**[Everyone knows](https://www.google.com/search?q=pringles+challenge) about the famous [Pringle Ring Challenge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sp47lvGR8Ek)**

[image: PRingle Ring]

Does anyone know how I could develop a theoretical model to predict its stability?

Comment: What kind of stability would you like to model? It's resistance against being pushed over? The load it can carry? It's strength in humid conditions?

Comment: @Steeven As a first step, the structural stability would be of issue, so the required resistance required for the vertical chips not to slide. The issue of material elasticity is also critical, but will come after.